# Strings not being translated on Woocommerce in Avada theme

Tags: wordpress, translation

Strings like 'out of stock', 'cart' and 'My Account' are not transltated to Hebrew in the website although they are translated in the .po file.

Wordpress version - 4.7.2
Woocommerce version - 2.6.13
Avada version - 5.0.5

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the GitHub repository *Theme-Fusion/Localization-l10n* which stores Avada translation files contributed by users, the strings 'out of stock' and 'My Account' are not translated to Hebrew.

You can :

1. download [this file](https://github.com/Theme-Fusion/Localization-l10n/blob/master/Avada/Avada-he.po),
2. add your own translations,
3. compile it to a .mo and
4. upload it to your *wp-content/languages/theme/* folder.

Before attempting to make your own translations, we suggest checking the pre-created language files that ships with Avada. All these files have been contributed by our amazing users and the amount of translated strings might vary.

Better, you can submit your own translations by following the [instructions provided by Theme Fusion](https://theme-fusion.com/avada-doc/translations/included-language-files/).